# MySQL CSV Import Fails - "Data too long for column 'air_date' at row 1"

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I'm trying to import a CSV file into a MySQL table and I'm having all kinds of trouble getting it to work.  Here's what I'm trying to do:

I am working on a video database and have an existing table with data already in it called episodes. Here's how it's set up:

`+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field        | Type                  | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| title        | varchar(40)           | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| media_id     | varchar(11)           | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| ep_info      | varchar(75)           | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| air_date     | varchar(20)           | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| trt          | varchar(8)            | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| times_played | mediumint(9) unsigned | NO   |     | 0                 |                             |
| last_played  | timestamp             | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| entered      | timestamp             | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| id           | int(10) unsigned      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| ep_desc      | varchar(300)          | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
+--------------+-----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+`

The primary key is the id field, with the title field set as a foreign key to the shows table.  The shows table looks like this:

```
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+------------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default    | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+------------+-------+
| title       | varchar(50) | NO   | PRI | NULL       |       |
| title_image | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL       |       |
| gif_image   | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL       |       |
| info_url    | varchar(30) | NO   |     | shows.html |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+------------+-------+
```

My CSV file is in the following format:

```
"Big Wolf On Campus","BWOC0102","Season 1 Episode 2: The Bookmobile","April 9, 1999";"21:57",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"Once every 70 years, a window of transference opens that offers Tommy a chance to pass his curse to another person. Merton volunteers but that same day a bookmobile shows up in Pleasantville and people start disappearing."
"Big Wolf On Campus","BWOC0103","Season 1 Episode 3: Butch Comes To Shove","April 16, 1999","21:06",NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"When a character from a 1950s educational film gets sick of the rules he decides to leave the movie for Pleasantville. While there Butch decides to find someone to bring back to his black-and-white world - and Stacey is at the top of his list."
```

During the import, I want the data in the CSV added to the existing data in the table.  I also want the last_played field set to NULL (only updated when the show plays), the entered field set with a current timestamp, and the id field auto_incremented with the next value for the table.

Here is my import statement:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'ytv.csv' INTO TABLE episodes
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

The resulting error message:

```
ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'air_date' at row 1
```

What am I doing wrong here?  It seems like the data is getting shifted over one column when it's importing (such that ep_info from the CSV is going into the air_date column) but I can't figure out why.  Any insight would be much appreciated for this MySQL novice.

Comment: **UPDATE** Found the error, there was a stray ';' after the air date in the first row.  
Now however, after fixing the CSV file I'm getting the following error:  

    ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ytv`.`episodes`, CONSTRAINT `fk_title` FOREIGN KEY (`title`) REFERENCES `shows` (`  

Anyone know what's going on here? I've been able to manually insert data with the same title into the episodes table.  The shows table does have a row with the title 'Big Wolf On Campus' in it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have some new episodes with no mapping entry in shows table. You can create a new table like episodes, remove any constraints, load the data to the new table, insert all missing show titles to your show table, then insert episodes from the new table to the episodes table.

Or you can delete the foreign key, load the data, amend you shows table, then add the foreign key back.